# Applet error on JRE 1.7u60 early release

Tags: java, security, applet

An early release of Java 7 update 60 is available on https://jdk7.java.net/.

I was testing out my applet on this release of JRE.
My applet works fine on JRE 1.7u45 with no warnings.

As per requirement of JRE 1.7u51 my applet has following attributes in manifest file.

```
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Trusted-Only: true
```

When i run my applet on JRE 1.7u60 early release, I get an error saying:

```
 Security exception: attempt to load a sandboxed jar as Trusted only.
```

Is this a known issue in JRE 1.7u60?

I am asking this because I am curious to understand if my applet run fine on JRE 1.7u51 if no warnings/errors are displayed in JRE 17u45 and i adhere to security requirements stated in

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/ria-checklist-2055184.html

ie jar files are signed and manifest file contains permissions attribute.

Comment: Have you checked the bug database?  If not, and you see nothing similar, best raise one and get the answer direct from Oracle.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have already raised a question on oracle forum. https://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se-snapshots-project-feedback/7u60-build-b01-lifeconnect-issues?force=689). I found some people facing issues with Liveconnect. Since this is an early release, i guess it might not be up to date/stable.

Comment: So what?  I said the **bug database,** not the (bloody) Oracle forums (which I abandoned long ago).  If I were still posting to them, my advice would be exactly the same..